# What is the recommended way to replace multiple strings in one large string in Python?

Tags: python, string

I have many string pairs and one large string (which is the content of a file). I need to replace each and every occurrence of the first member in each pair with the respective second one.

For instance, having pairs ("AA", "BB") and ("qq", "rt") I need to replace every occurrence of **AA** with **BB** and of **qq** with **rt**.

The strings in the pairs are all unique, so the order of replacements does not matter on the final result.

My python code is the most naive - I apply the string.replace method in succession until all the pairs are exhausted:

```
>>> s="frsfsdAAsdfvsdfvqqdsff"
>>> pairs=[('AA', 'BB'), ('qq', 'rt')]
>>> for p in pairs:
...   s=s.replace(p[0], p[1])
...
>>> s
'frsfsdBBsdfvsdfvrtdsff'
>>>
```

I believe this is a bad solution for large strings. Can anyone suggest a more efficient one?

**The question is about how to do it in Python.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's something else wrong with your proposed solution: after the first replacement is made the resulting string could match and the same characters could be replaced again. For example your solution would not give the desired result if you tried to swap `'qq'` and `'ff'` by setting `pairs = [('qq','ff'), ('ff','qq')]`.

You could try this instead:

```
>>> d = dict(pairs)
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(k) for k in d))
>>> pattern.sub(lambda k:d[k.group()], s))
frsfsdBBsdfvsdfvrtdsff
```

Comment: Oh, but I have explicitly stated in the question and I quote: **The strings in the pairs are all unique, so the order of replacements does not matter on the final result.** Even if the order part is irrelevant, the precondition still holds - all the strings are unique.

Comment: @mark: That makes no difference at all. Your solution **still does not work**. I could easily find another example where all the strings are unique but your solution will still **fail** to give the expected result.

Comment: Why is that? `string.replace` replaces all the occurrences - `'mmmAAmmmmAAmmmAA'.replace('AA', 'BB') == 'mmmBBmmmmBBmmmBB'` is `True`

Comment: I think I get it now, the combination of replacement string with the other characters may produce new matches, which would then be replaced. Good catch, thanks.